# Is there an R function for removing a specific snippet of the data in a column?

Tags: r, data-analysis

So I have a data frame that includes a column like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzAWU.png)

And I would like to remove the operator as well as the numbers to the right of it, i.e. so the first entry would just say 51.81 rather than 51.81 - 11.19. How would I go about this? I feel like using a for loop might work but I'm unsure of the syntax required.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post screenshots - we cant copy paste from them. Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) using `dput`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by a `-` or `+` and other characters, and replace with blank (`""`)

```
df1$xG <- as.numeric(sub("\\s*[-+]+.*", "", df1$xG))
```